# What is the right type for my onClick event here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

What is the right type for my onClick event here?

Live demo: [demo live](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-estrela-rts1y5?file=/src/Data.tsx:0-637)

```
interface BtnItem {
  label: string;
  onClick?: (id: string) => void;
}

interface DataProps {
  id: string;
  buttons: BtnItem[];
}

const DataButton: React.FC<{
  button: BtnItem;
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void;
}> = ({ button, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={onClick}>
      <div>{button.label}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Data: React.FC<DataProps> = ({ id, buttons }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1> What is the problem here? </h1>
      {buttons.map((button) => (
        <DataButton button={button} onClick={button.onClick} />
      ))}
      ;
    </>
  );
};

export default Data;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Type '((id: string) => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'.
  Type '(id: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'id' and 'event' are incompatible.
      Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: Is [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-meadow-5llggi) what you want?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-estrela-rts1y5?file=/src/Data.tsx  ur so close assume now I add a dialog with open,  setOpen method whose are boolean in dialog component now it says mouse event is not assigned to the parameter of type boolean, why?

Comment: I don't have your dialog component + why are you passing a mouse event to a boolean anyways? `onClick` expects an **event handler**, not a function that takes a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you what type it's looking for:

```
(event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void
```

So the interface would be:

```
interface BtnItem {
  label: string;
  onClick?: (event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to keep the same interface, you'd need to pass a string instead of the whole event object.  For example:

```
onClick={() => button.onClick && button.onClick(id)}
```

---

Basically, at its simplest what's happening is the function on the interface in your code is expecting a `string` but the `onClick` event sends a `MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>`.  So either the function needs to expect that type, or when calling the function you need to send the type it expects.

Comment: `button.onClick?.(id)` would also behave the same

Comment: Thanks david for another suggestion I will accept this answer  bcoz @cats did not provide the answer , I tried to pass my component databutton to dialog which conatin open and setOpen method but are bolean check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-estrela-rts1y5?file=/src/Data.tsx  typescript give error: mouse event is not assigned to the parameter of type boolean why?

Comment: @TheDeadMan: The link provided has different errors when I view it.  But it *sounds like* the same problem.  If you're trying to pass a `MouseEvent<>` type to a function which expects a `boolean` type then it will fail for the same reason why it failed when trying to pass a `MouseEvent<>` type to a function which expects a `string` type.